# Redirect to authorize page on session time out

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

### Brief Introduction about the web app:

I'm developing a web app on CakePHP 3.2 where user authentication is a two step process.

Every user has username, password, PIN, along with other fields.

**Step 1:** users/login - Enter username and password.

**Step 2:** users/pin_authorize - If step 1 is successful, then enter pin.

### What I need:

Every time the user is inactive for about 30 mins, I want the user to be redirected to the pin_authorize page and not the main login page. The user would be able to access the other pages only if he inserts the correct PIN.

### What I've tried so far:

```
 // AppController

 public function initialize() {

        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('Auth',[
            'loginAction' => [
                'plugin'        => 'Admin',
                'controller'    => 'Users',
                'action'        => 'login'
            ],
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'plugin'        => 'Admin',
                'controller'    => 'Users',
                'action'        => 'pinAuthorization'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'plugin'        => 'Admin',
                ...
            ]
         ]);

   }

// UsersController

public function pinAuthorization() {

        if (!$this->Auth->user('id')) {

            return $this->redirect([
                'plugin'     => 'Admin',
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action'     => 'login'
            ]);
        }

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            if ($this->Users->pinAuthorize($this->request->data['pin'])) {
                $this->request->session()->write("PinAuthStatus", 1);
                return $this->redirect([
                    'plugin'     => 'Admin',
                    'controller' => 'Users',
                    'action'     => 'dashboard'
                ]);
            }

            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid PIN.'));
        }

        $this->viewBuilder()->layout(false);
    }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You will have to be a little more specific about _the actual technical problem_ that you are facing, as currently your question is basically asking for a ready made solution for your task, or step-by-step instructions glaced with opinions. There is nothing in your code that looks like it would have anything to do with that 30 minute timer, personally I would have no clue what to post as an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating a [cookie](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/cookie.html) after the user has successfully [logged in](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in) that expires in 30 minutes and is updated every time [isAuthorized](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#using-controllerauthorize) is validated. You can then do a [redirect](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#redirecting-to-other-pages) to the pin authorization page within the isAuthorized if the cookie has expired and the session still exists.